# Accessing Web APi endpoint route from within endpoint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

So I have a web api created with .net6, with an endpoint like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/controller/action/{parameter}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ActionResponse>> GetValue(int parameterId)
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to get the value of the route of the endpoint from within the code of the endpoint?

So far I have tried:

```
var controller = RouteData.Values["controller"]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
var action = RouteData.Values["action"]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

and:

```
var endpoint = HttpContext.Request.Path.Value ?? string.Empty;
```

But neither of these quite get what I'm after.

Basically, I want to be able to populate a variable with the value of:

```
var value = "~/api/controller/action/{parameter}";
```

Without hardcoding the value into the endpoint's code.

Answer (score 0):

> `[Route("~/api/controller/action/{parameter}")]`
>
> I'm not sure how/if it works in your case at all ‍♂️

❗ There are 2 issues in your example:

1. `{parameter}` in route doesn't match method argument `parameterId`.
2. There are hardcoded values `controller` and `action` in the route instead of tokens `[controller]` and `[action]`.

---

You can find available tokens in the docs:

> The following keywords are reserved route parameter names when using Controllers or Razor Pages:
>
> - action
> - area
> - controller
> - handler
> - page
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#reserved-routing-names

---

✅ I defined action in the controller like this:

[image: Controller action]

Then in the runtime I see these values in the debugger:

[image: Values in the debugger]